# Add label between input field and input-group-addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, validation, change-password

In a user management interface, my application provides a password input field. This field is a Bootsrap `input-group` with both, a `form-control` and an `input-group-addon` that holds an icon.

Now I tried to introduce a **password strength meter**, which works fine technically. However, the design breaks, as soon as the user enters the first character in the password field. The height of the `input-group-addon` increases, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Input field with password strength meter]

I prepared a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq61ucht/) to showcase the issue. Additionally, here is the relevant part of the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control ok-password" ng-class="(joinTeamForm.password.$dirty && joinTeamForm.password.$invalid) ? 'error' : ''" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-required="true" ng-model="password">

    <div class="label password-count" ng-class="password.length > 7 ? 'label-success' : 'label-danger'" ng-cloak>{{ password | passwordCount:7 }}</div>

    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent the `input-group-addon` from changing its size or insert the label with the password length count properly? Does Bootstrap provide better means to insert such an indicator within a text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the position is set to `relative`, hence it also considers the label while calculating height for `input-group`.

I changed the position from `relative` to `absolute` so that label will not be considered.

```
.password-count {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 45px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Check out updated JS Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/v98h71ry/

This is where the relatively positioned item will be placed:

[image: Label placement after position change]

As you've entered `bottom` and `right` positions, it re-positions as defined, but the initial height of `input-group` remains as is.

Comment: I had to use ``position: absolute; bottom: 9px; right: 50px;`` to achieve the exact same look as before, but basically your suggested change fixed it. Thank you!